# Is the .NET Framework installed by default on Vista?

Tags: .net, windows-vista

I'm writing a console application that will be deployed with an installation of an application we are writing.  The console app aims to fix a bug in vista that will allow our application to be installed correctly in Vista.  The console application works fine, but can I count on the .NET framework being installed on all Vista machines - is it installed by default?

Comment: A quick Google search would have told you that. Stop being lazy.

Comment: just curious - what is the bug in Vista you are trying to work around?

Comment: Vista doesn't perform a desktop refresh after the installation of new software, therefore any new icons you deploy to the desktop wont be visable.  You can perform a desktop refresh by calling down into the windows api using   [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern void SHChangeNotify(Enumeration.HChangeNotifyEventID wEventId,
                                           UInt32 flags,
                                           IntPtr dwItem1,
                                           IntPtr dwItem2);

There is a hotfix to fix the bug but we can't count on that being installed.

Comment: Matt Lacey - I wasn't being lazy.  I had viewed a couple of sources but wanted to utilise the group research power of the Stakoverflow users to further confirm my research.    I also thought the question would be a useful resource for others.

Comment: Sorry - mat, that wasnt intended for you.

Comment: If the question is relevant to programming, it's perfectly fine to ask it, whether it can be found by Googling or not. This isn't one of *those* sites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/12/27/install-microsoft-net-framework-11-on-windows-vista-fix-regsvcsexe-fails-error/):

> Windows Vista comes packaged with
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.0,
>   but not version 1.1, which may still
>   required by some applications

So if your console application targets v 2.0 or v 3.0 you should be OK

Answer (score 3):

> The .NET Framework 3.0 is installed by default on Microsoft Windows Vista

[Source: Deploying Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480198.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of which versions of .Net are installed on which versions of Windows on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions).

- Windows XP and before don't come with .Net
- Windows Server 2003 comes with .Net 1.1
- Windows Vista comes with .Net 3.0
- Windows 2008 comes with .Net 3.0
- Windows 2008 R2 comes with .Net 3.5
- Windows 7 is probably going to come with .Net 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Yes .Net 3.0 is installed by default on Vista

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3 is installed on Vista by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [See here for an overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions).

Answer (score 1):

[According to the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480198.aspx#netfx30_topic6) (emphasis mine):

> The .NET Framework 3.0 **is installed by
>   default on Microsoft Windows Vista**. On
>   Microsoft Windows Server code-named
>   "Longhorn", you can install the .NET
>   Framework as a Windows Feature using
>   Roles Management tools.