# Is there a version of the .Net Redistributable bundled with all supported versions of Windows?

Tags: .net, redistributable

Is there a specific version of .Net that I can target that is bundled with all versions of Windows of XP SP2 and higher?

We are trying to create a simple setup stub without having to resort to a low-level C/C++ app... currently something is cooked up in VB6, but there's a fair amount of low-level network code that I would much rather rewrite in .Net -- which would be trivial if only we could rely on the presence of a given version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438937/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-installed-on-windows-xp-vista-and-7

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438937/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-installed-on-windows-xp-vista-and-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot count on having .NET available on a XP machine.  Windows Update might have been disabled.  No problem on Vista (3.0) and Windows 7 (3.5 SP1).