# How to Run C# Exe without .Net Framework

Tags: .net

I am using Visual Studio 2010.
I made a C# project and it runs perfectly on my Computer.

Problem is this that when Application is run on another Computer, that ask for .Net Framework.
Everybody doesn't have administrator Access to install .Net Framework and also peoples don't want to install that.

What alternative i should follow to sort out this problem?
(Specifically for Windows 7).

Comment: Force them to install! Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework

Comment: you have Win7 but not the latest framework?

Comment: As @IvanCrojachKaračić noted, you should have at least .NET 3.5 (I think) if you're running Win7.  Unless you're using features that are specific to .NET 4, you should be able to change your app to target the 3.5 framework; at that point it should work.

Comment: Er, wait, they are willing to install *your* software but not the software created by the largest software company in the world?  How did Windows end up on their machines?  This problem needs to be solved by your customer's IT staff, nothing you can do.

Comment: .NET only "compiles" your code when it's actually run.  That is, the .NET compiler generate IL ("Intermediate Language"); but the IL is not converted to machine code until it actually runs.  (This way, the resulting machine code can take full advantage of the hardware that it's running on; the alternative would be compiling to a "least common denominator" of, say, a (1st-gen) Pentium.)  so the short answer is, .NET isn't designed for this,  although there are 3rd-party tools (see link above) that claim to solve your problem.

Answer (score 22):

Windows contains a version of .NET by default. Here's a listing of them.

> #### XP
>
> - <kbd>.NET v1.0</kbd>  -- Service pack 1
> - <kbd>.NET v2.0</kbd>  -- Service packs 2 & 3
>
> #### Vista
>
> - <kbd>.NET v3.0</kbd>  -- All service packs
>
> #### Windows 7
>
> - <kbd>.NET v3.5</kbd>  -- All versions and service packs
>
> #### Windows 8
>
> - <kbd>.NET v4.0</kbd> + <kbd>Metro UI</kbd> available.
>
> #### Windows 8.1
>
> - <kbd>.Net v4.5</kbd> + <kbd>Metro UI</kbd> available.
>
> #### Windows 10
>
> - <kbd>.Net v4.6</kbd> + <kbd>Metro UI</kbd> + <kbd>Universal Apps</kbd> available.
>
> #### Note:
>
> All contains <kbd>.NET v4.6</kbd> if <kbd>Windows Update</kbd> is enabled. (Not for all versions of windows)

#### Options of deployment:

> There are several options of deployment.
>
> - Checking for .NET in installation. (Install systems like NSIS support this).
>     See [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_ensure_a_required_version_of_.NET_Framework_is_installed) for more info.
> - If you want to deploy portable app, notify users to install the required .NET version. (easier)
> - Target .NET 2.0 and all users are able to run your app since I think nobody is using XP SP1. (easiest. I use this to deploy mine.)

**EDIT**

There needs some clarity with some other answers, so I'm quoting [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#endnote_a1none) Wikipedia note.

> .NET Framework 1.0 is integral OS component of Windows XP Media Center edition or Tablet PC edition. Installation CDs for the Home editions and the Professional editions of Windows XP SP1, SP2 or SP3 comes with .NET Framework installation packages.

Comment: `All contains .NET v4.5 if Windows Update is enabled.` - Do you have a source for that? That might break some software as it's a _replacement_ to 4.0 .

Comment: @ispiro Yeah, not all versions, I'm on Win 7, so it updated for me. Will correct that.

Comment: Hi, can I confirm about this? Other answer mentions that XP does not have .NET installed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438937/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-installed-on-windows-xp-vista-and-7

Comment: @user77177928 Yes, as stated in Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#endnote_a1none

Answer (score 5):

No way! CLR is absolutely needed for managed apps.

Answer (score 3):

The only alternative is to not use a programming language that is based on the .net framework.

If you're writing a c# application, then the .net framework is required.

Perhaps you want to create a c++ application instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting Windows 7 or later version of the OS, then just compile your program using C# 3.5. The version 3.5 of the framework is part of Windows 7.

I guess you were compiling C# 4.0 code.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong but windows 7 comes with .Net framework installed. Windows Vista  comes with installed .net framework and I believe this is valid for windows 7 as well. 
And to answer your question - it is not possible to run the exe on a machine that does not have the framework as the program compiles to intermediate language that is only "understandable" by the Common language runtime(CLR)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [Spoon](http://spoon.net/Studio/) (earlier XenoCode) that can wrap everything that your app needs and runs it in as a standalone.

From their site:

> Spoon Studio
>
> Easily virtualize all of your applications for instant,
>   zero-install delivery on Spoon Server and Spoon.net.
>
> Spoon Studio lets you convert your existing software applications into virtual applications
>   that run with no installs, conflicts, or dependencies.