# Java Products runs even don't have JVM in pc - How?

Tags: c#, java, deployment, operating-system

Likewise, how the Microsoft products runs even i don't have any .net framework, Vc++ compiler or whatever. Let see the situation, i brought new Pc with windows Xp and then i install NFS Most wanted or any equivalent generation games. We know that, it will run. I don't know how it cause?.

May be this question duplicate me: [How to run any C# project .exe without .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611023/how-to-run-c-sharp-exe-without-net-framework)

Let discuss and share!

Comment: All applications that rely on the C++ redistribution or .Net libraries or DirectX or OpenGL install them as part of there installation process...

Comment: When you install a game all required runtime dependencies are installed with it by the installer.

Comment: @To All So what about the C# winform application. Can i run without .net Framework?. If can, how?

Comment: No, but see my answer below.

Comment: Ok. If I had the C# 3.0 Winform application which was bundled by .Net framework 3.5 with Windows XP SP3. Can i run these application in Windows 7 without .Net?

Comment: @MadProgrammmer You replied correctly what i expect. Then why u hold me. What unclear in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 and 8 come with pre-installed versions of the .net runtime. (Version 2.0 for Win7, 4.5 for Win8 if I'm not misstaken). Also, any updates are deployed using Windows Update, so you probabbly don't even notice when you install a new version.

That's why most .net applications will "just run".

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Whenever you install any game/ software, it will also install redistributable C++ /DirectX etc (usually). During installation itself
>      it will ask whether you want to "upgrade" your version of C++ or
>      DirectX if you have another older version installed, otherwise it will
>      install C++/DirectX. This version of DirectX/C++ will be used by the
>      program. You can go to your Control Panel --> Ad/Remove programs and see various versions of redistributable C++ installed (if you had/have installed many games/ software)
> 2. Without a JVM, nothing in java runs. The JRE might also be installed by a program but will be locally
>      linked i.e, you can't see it in your path and it will be uninstalled
>      when the program is uninstalled.

Comment: What are the steps followed for execute C# Winform application without .net framework.

Comment: @UdanPirappu - No, you must have an underlying framework to run any application be it Java (JRE) or C# (.Net)  or WinForm. The runtimes will be installed automatically for you, go check your Add/Remove programs, they will be there.

Comment: What are the procedure will follow[in hierarchy] if somebody develop and deploy the software which made in the C# 3.0 Winform and .Net 3.5?