# What version of the .NET Framework is the safest to code with?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, windows

Our professor asked us to create a machine problem that is standalone. This project has also been given in his previous students, and seeing their code, they either used C++ or C#. If I remember correctly from what I have researched before, C# programs are not standalone because of the .NET Framework and some other components you need to install to run it. Not all computers have .NET Framework. On the other hand, I also remember reading an article suggesting the safest .NET Framework to work with because a specific version of Windows OS has it pre-installed.

By the way, I'm not familiar with Turbo Delphi. It is commonly suggested for those who wants to create standalone programs.

Going back, I'm working halfway on my project now and I'm coding in C#. I'm thinking of just changing the .NET Framework so that my professor could run it on his Windows laptop without requiring any DLL or other components. What is the safest .NET Framework to code with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What version of the .NET framework is installed on Windows XP, Vista, and 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438937/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-installed-on-windows-xp-vista-and-7)

Comment: The person who marked this as opinion based did not read the question.

Comment: The real answer to this question is you should just ask your professor -- he or she will say 4.0 -- because as a student you want to learn the latest.

Comment: Really depends on what "standalone" means. Truly standalone would rule .net out as you nee the correct framework installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.0, as it has the greatest penetration of any .NET framework (being that it's the earliest).  1.0/1.1 are not forwards-compatible with 2.0/later, so I would advise against those.

Comment: As a side note, what @Sukasa means by penetration is that 2.0 apps will work on machines which have 3.0 and 4.0 installed.